# Get file version and assembly version of DLL files in the current directory and all sub directories

Tags: powershell

I would like to be able to get the file version and assembly version of all DLL files within a directory and all of its subdirectories. I'm new to programming, and I can't figure out how to make this loop work.

I have this PowerShell code to get the assembly version (taken from a forum):

```
$strPath = 'c:\ADMLibrary.dll'
$Assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::Loadfile($strPath)

$AssemblyName = $Assembly.GetName()
$Assemblyversion = $AssemblyName.version
```

And this as well:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -recurse | %{ $_.VersionInfo }
```

How can I make a loop out of this so that I can return the assembly version of all files within a directory?

Answer (score 78):

Here is a pretty one liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo
```

In short for PowerShell version 2:

```
ls -fi *.dll -r | % { $_.versioninfo }
```

In short for PowerShell version 3 as suggested by [tamasf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024317/tamasf):

```
ls *.dll -r | % versioninfo
```

Comment: In short: ls *.dll -r | % versioninfo

Comment: This will only yield the FileVersion but not the AssemblyVersion

Comment: For managed dll's, to get the real/updated version info, .NET is really the only way to go. http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/22/powershell-load-assembly-without-locking-file/ Look at the "update" down below, the rest is over-complicating it :p

Answer (score 49):

As an ugly one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        try {
            $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty FileVersion ($_.VersionInfo.FileVersion)
            $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty AssemblyVersion (
                [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version
            )
        } catch {}
        $_
    } |
    Select-Object Name,FileVersion,AssemblyVersion
```

If you only want the current directory, then obviously leave out the `-Recurse` parameter. If you want all files instead of just DLLs, then remove the `-Filter` parameter and its argument. The code is (hopefully) pretty straightforward.

I'd suggest you spin off the nasty parts within the `try` block into separate functions since that will make error handling less awkward here.

Sample output:

```
Name                                    FileVersion     AssemblyVersion
----                                    -----------     ---------------
Properties.Resources.Designer.cs.dll    0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0
My Project.Resources.Designer.vb.dll    0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0
WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.dll         1.0.0.0         1.0.0.0
WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.dll         1.0.0.0         1.0.0.0
WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.dll         1.0.0.0         1.0.0.0
```

Comment: This works, but unfortunately it loads the files and never releases them ... Run it and then try to delete one of those files.

Comment: That is indeed a drawback. You can circumvent this by spawning a new PowerShell instance: `powershell -NoProfile -OutputFormat XML -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand  |%{$_}` with `$encodedCommand` being the Base64-encoded variant of the above snippet (see `powershell /?` for a sample how to obtain it). This will yield the same objects that would otherwise be produced, but the shell loading the files is no longer alive now.

Comment: I am trying to load the assemblies into new AppDomain and unload it later, but it does not work - the assembly loader looks for assemblies in PowerShell directory (C:/windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0) even though I set the base directory when creating the new domain...

Comment: @Karel, what exactly would be wrong with just spawning a new process?

Comment: I didn't say that! I just tried it and it locked those files. And then tried different approach and that didn't work. Yes, spawning new process is the solution here.

Comment: The AppDomain approach should work too, but it's somewhat difficult to pull off, I guess.

Comment: You can use `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName` to get the AssemblyName (and hence the AssemblyVersion) without loading the assembly

Comment: @Wayne: Oh, that's way nicer. Thanks.

Comment: This actually works for C++/CLI assemblies that don't have Version resources

Answer (score 8):

Let Select-Object create the properties

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse | Select-Object Name,@{n='FileVersion';e={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}},@{n='AssemblyVersion';e={[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version}}
```

And Sample output is similar

```
Name                                           FileVersion AssemblyVersion
----                                           ----------- ---------------
CI.EntityFramework.Initialization.dll          1.0.0.0     1.0.0.0
Castle.Core.dll                                3.3.0.43    3.3.0.0
Castle.Windsor.dll                             3.3.0.51    3.3.0.0
Mutare.VitalLink.dll                           1.0.0.0     1.0.0.0
Newtonsoft.Json.dll                            9.0.1.19813 9.0.0.0
```

Comment: NOTE: this skips .exe files which may be relevant. I just use `*.*`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pretty one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse | ForEach-Object `
{
    return [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        FileVersion = $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion
        AssemblyVersion = ([Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version)
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Name            FileVersion AssemblyVersion
----            ----------- ---------------
Minimatch.dll   1.1.0.0     1.1.0.0
VstsTaskSdk.dll 1.0.0.0     1.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Joey's answer, but exploiting some handy behaviour for implicit exception handling. First add an extension property:

```
Update-TypeData -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -MemberType ScriptProperty -MemberName AssemblyVersion -Value { [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($this.FullName).Version }
```

That can optionally be placed into your profile for reuse. Then the actual selection is just e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse | Select-Object Name,AssemblyVersion
```

---

*As a side-note, the main reason I'm posting this as an additional answer is for the benefit of PowerShell noobs like myself: it took me a long time to figure out that `$_` in Joey's answer needs to be turned into `$this` in the definition given to `Update-TypeData`*.

Answer (score 0):

```
$j = 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 8.0\' # this is the path of foler where you want check your dlls 
$files = get-childitem $j -recurse -include *.dll # this is the command thatwill check all the dlls in that folder 

foreach ($i in $files) {
   $verison = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($i).FileVersion
   Write-Host  "$i ----> $verison "
} # loop is used where it will travel throuhg all the files of the specified folder and check the verion and will print it
```

Comment: please add description or comment on your answer

Comment: Not familiar with PHP, but wouldn't `\'` escape the quote, meaning you haven't ended the String?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer need more explanation about how the code works to be a good answer.