# How to check the version of an assembly (dll)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have c# application and when I made a change, I am getting the error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in 
>   WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load type
>   'TradeIdeas.TIProData.OddsMakerColumnConfiguration' from assembly
>   'TIProData, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’.

This message says the version number of dll (TIProData) is 1.0.0.0.  I think there is a later version available.  How can I tell the version number of a dll on my machine?

Comment: RIght click on the DLL go to Properties > Details. Version 1.0.0.0 Looks like its a development version of the DLL

Comment: That is the file version, not the assembly version @AlexAnderson

Comment: Open csproj file in text editor and find that dll reference, you can change version there, seems there is 1.0.0.0 hard coded

Comment: See powershell commands in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267009/get-file-version-and-assembly-version-of-dll-files-in-the-current-directory-and

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the assembly file version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909555/how-can-i-get-the-assembly-file-version)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (free), [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), [ILDASM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to get the assembly version.

You usually can find ILDASM in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe` (where `v8.1A` is the version of the Windows SDK installed).

ILDASM:

[image: ildasm]

Reflector:

[image: reflector]

Comment: Or [Jetbrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), which is also free.

Comment: Btw it is absurd how hard Microsoft makes something this basic

Comment: Why is it different from the dll version from windows explorer file details?

Answer (score 9):

There is a couple of ways to do it:

- If you reference the dll in Visual Studio right click it (in ProjectName/References folder) and select "Properties" you have "Version" and "Runtime Version" there.
- In File Explorer when you right click the dll file and select properties there is a "File Version" and "Product Version" there.
- Alternatively, investigate it in code:

  ```
  Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("TestAssembly.dll");
  Version ver = assembly.GetName().Version;
  ```

Comment: Caution - the "FileVersion" shown in the properties tab is NOT the same thing as AssemblyVersion which is the id used for binding redirects or assembly loading.

Comment: @NeilMacMullen Yes! This has bitten me a few times.  A workaround I found is to open the DLL with 7-zip and read the Assembly Version from .rsrc/version.txt .  Baffles me why this isn't displayed in the File Properties dialog along with the rest of it.

Comment: You should remove the middle bullet mentioning File Version and Product Version. It is true, but it implies that these are synonymous with the assembly version because that was the question and you have listed it as one of the "ways to do it".

Answer (score 5):

You can use `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(string path)` from a little util app.

Further details here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

If you know Class, that belongs to assembly, you can use GetTypeInfo

```
var runtimeVersion = typeof(MyClass)
.GetTypeInfo()
.Assembly
.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>();

var version = runtimeVersion.Version;
```

The example is for .Net Core
from  https://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2017/06/27/how-to-deal-with-assembly-version-in-net-core.aspx

Answer (score 3):

From Powershell (PSCore):
`$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$pwd\System.Memory.dll")`
Besides `$assembly.FullName` you can pick up any other prop from the object.

Comment: This approach silently gives the wrong answer if a DLL with the same name but in a different folder happens to be loaded already by the PowerShell process. In that case, it gives the assembly version of the already loaded DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by JamesLucas' answer, you can create this `assversion.fsx` script and just run it with `dotnet fsi asseversion.fsx ./path/to/your.dll`:

```
if fsi.CommandLineArgs.Length < 2 then
    System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Please supply assembly path")
    exit 1
let arg = fsi.CommandLineArgs.[1]
System.Console.WriteLine(arg)
System.Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(arg).ToString())
```