# How can I check for the presence of .DLL files using cmd.exe or PowerShell, without changing permissions?

Tags: powershell, cmd, dll, attributes, get-childitem

How can I check for the presence of these https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1841751#c4 .DLL files in C:\ProgramData and child containers, using cmd.exe or PowerShell?

Preferably one-liners rather that scripts.

Without changing access permissions of any files or folders. (When using explorer I would have to change the permissions).

Have not tried anything yet as I am not sure what to do exactly, or if it will do something irreversible.
Not even sure if this would show the attributes for the DLLs without the need to change permissions.
Thought of using Get-Childitem, but this:-
[Get file version and assembly version of DLL files in the current directory and all sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267009/get-file-version-and-assembly-version-of-dll-files-in-the-current-directory-and)
says items stay loaded and can't be deleted "*unfortunately it loads the files and never releases them*". Unless using code I don't understand to spawn a new PowerShell instance.

Comment: AFAIK Mozilla isn't a managed, but a native application, so this answer should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12663969/7571258

Comment: @zett42 Thanks, would it load the files and never release them? As stated in comments for [https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269781](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269781) or is that issue due to something in the code only in that answer?

Comment: Eric, the loading and not releasing problem in the linked post is specific to _.NET_ DLLs, as @zett42 notes, which Firefox isn't using. (Aside from that, they _are_ released, namely when the _process exits_, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269781/45375) now uses a technique where the problem doesn't occur to begin with). Your question is about file permissions, and therefore unrelated to the linked post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, the subdirectories of the hidden system directory `C:\ProgramData` (`$env:ProgramData` or `$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE`)  fall into one of 3 categories:

- (a) Some can be read by anyone.
- (b) Some are protected from being read by *non-elevated* processes (run without administrative privileges).
- (c) Some are even protected from having their contents read by *elevated* processes.

*Interactively*, for directories in (b) and (c), the current user can persistently gain access via a one-time action in File Explorer, which *changes the file-system permissions* (ACLs):

- File Explorer offers to perform this change on accessing an affected folder, via a UAC dialog (which means that if the current user is an administrator, only *confirming* the dialog is sufficient; otherwise, an administrator's credentials are needed).

*Programmatically*, (for directories that haven't already been "unlocked" interactively), you can only gain access to category (b) *ad hoc, without changing permissions*:<sup>[1]</sup>

- That is, you must ensure that your [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) calls are made from an *elevated* PowerShell session (the same requirements as discussed for the UAC dialog above apply):
- *Interactively*, right-click your PowerShell taskbar / Start Menu icon, select `Run as Administrator`, and confirm the UAC dialog, then run your `Get-ChildItem` / `Test-Path` command.
- *Programmatically*, from an existing *non*-elevated PowerShell session:

  - Use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Verb RunAs (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path` to start an interactive elevated session, then submit your command in that new session.
  - If you want to start an elevated session and submit a command *in a single operation*, do something like the following:

```bash
Start-Process -Verb RunAs (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path @'
  -NoExit -Command

  Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err -Recurse -Force -Filter *.dll -LiteralPath C:\ProgramData  |
    ForEach-Object VersionInfo |
    Where-Object FileVersion -in '1.0.0.26638', '1.0.0.26793', '1.0.0.27567', '1.0.0.29915', '1.0.0.31122'

  if ($err) {
    $notAuthorized, $others = $err.Where({ $_.Exception -is [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] }, 'Split')
    if ($notAuthorized) {
      Write-Warning "You are not authorized to access the following paths:`n $($notAuthorized.TargetObject -join "`n  ")"
    }
    if ($others) {
      Write-Warning "The following unexpected errors occurred:`n $($others.ForEach('ToString') -join "`n  ")"
    }
  }
'@.Replace('"', '\"')
```

Note:

- The **above is an *example* command that tries to find malware DLLs by *specific version numbers* only**, which can yield false positives or may not find anything at all if the version numbers don't match your scenario.
- As the [linked bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1841751) states, both the path and the specific file name of the malware DLLs can vary, so searching by path / name won't work.
- To further narrow down matches, so you'll have two tweak the command to also look for the following, per [this comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1841751#c4):

> combination of these four pieces of information (Timestamp, CheckSum=0, ImageSize, File version)

- I assume that `Timestamp` corresponds to the `.LastWriteTime` property of the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances that `Get-ChildItem` emits.
- I'm unclear on how to obtain `CheckSum` in PowerShell (in the bug report it was obtained with WinDbg).
- On a general note, if you're targeting `C:\ProgramData` directly such as in combination with `-Recurse`), you *must* also use `-Force`, because PowerShell will otherwise not find the directory, because it is hidden.

---

<sup>[1] *Conceivably*, there is a way through impersonation or ad-hoc modification of the privileges of the user token associated with the current process, but I am not sure.</sup>

Comment: Great, thanks, delay as learning more PowerShell to help understand answer.  Sorry I have a few quick queries:- 1. If I started from an Admin PowerShell, could I loose the part before `@'`?  2. What is this part for: `.Replace('"', '\"')`?  3. Why the Here-string?  4. Can any other errors that occur also be seen or counted?  I thought maybe Timestamp was for the (digital) signature.

Comment: @Eric: Re 1. In an elevated session, you can run the content of the here-string after `-NoExit -Command` directly. Re 2. `.Replace('"', '\"')` ``\``-escapes the embedded `"` chars., which is required for `"` chars. to be preserved when calling via `powershell.exe [-Command]`. Doing this programmatically helps keep the actual command text more readable. Re 3: The here-string is purely for readability and not needing to escape embedded quoting. Re 4: Please see my update: I've changed the error handling code to show permission errors, specifically, as well as any others (there shouldn't be any).

Comment: Thanks, helpful comment. PowerShell result gives 2 not authorized paths. Same result with either Admin PowerShell or if I use the whole code, same if 1st or revised version.  It does not mention any files that were found, nor any that were 'not found'. Should I be expecting it to show either one or the other, rather than a blank result for that part?

Comment: @Eric, the command in the answer is an _example_ that filters by _hard-coded version numbers_ (gleaned from the Mozilla bug report). If you simply want to enumerate all files in `C:\ProgramData`, remove the `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` calls.

Comment: Fast reply, thank you. I was wanting to check if those files are there or not. Checking by version numbers as in the example seems logical to me. If I get a blank result for that part, does it mean .dll files with those version numbers are not there, unless they are under the 2 'not authorized' paths?

Comment: @Eric, yes, exactly.