# How do I rename an executable in visual studio based on it's version number?

Tags: visual-studio, version, build-process, .net-assembly

I have a software product which gets wrapped in a custom installer I wrote. I'd like that installer executable to be named based on the assembly it contains.

Is there any way to retrieve an assembly's version number and use it at compile time? I can't see any mention of version numbers in the macros listed in visual studio (e.g. something like `$(TargetPath)`)..

Comment: you could use a batch file to fetch the version number, and invoke it in a post-build event that renames/copies the installer executable

Comment: What command would you use on the command line to retrieve a .net assembly version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037008/assembly-version-from-command-line

Comment: Doesn't appear to work: `Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\jonc\MyApp.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At line:1 char:39
+ [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ("C:\Users\jonc\MyApp.exe")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException` ...does that not work on mixed mode assemblies?

Comment: sorry, no idea; I just posted it becasue it was the first match I found; another possibility is that it cannot find some dll the exe depend on.. You could try the second answer? Or parse the AssemblyVersion.cs file?